# Blur filter not working as intended (blur filter does not update to match gradient animation)

Tags: css

I am trying to create a text with a blurred background so it looks like the text has an aura. So far the code I have is

```css
.testRainbow {
  position:fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.testRainbow::before {
  content:'';
  position:fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  height:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #03a9f4, #f441a4, #ffeb3b, #03a9f4);
  background-size: 400%;
  -moz-animation: slideRainbow 8s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: slideRainbow 8s linear infinite;
  animation: slideRainbow 8s linear infinite;
  -moz-filter: blur(1em);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1em);
  filter: blur(1em);
  z-index: -1;
}
@keyframes slideRainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 400%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideRainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 400%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideRainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 400%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class='testRainbow'>test</h1>
```

I tested it and it works on Chrome, but it does not work on Safari. Further, I checked that it does not work on mobile Chrome, which is interesting because it works when I open Chrome from my desktop.

The linear gradient is changing as it is supposed to for all browsers, but for the ones that don't work, it seems the blur is not being updated. I checked that while I resize or zoom in, the blur updates to the current gradient. What needs to be changed? Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**
I fixed the problem, and ran into another problem. I added the `filter: blur` inside the keyframes as follows:

```
@keyframes slideRainbow (
    0% {
      background-position: 0%;
      filter: blur(1em);
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 0%;
      filter: blur(1em);
    }
}
```

I only have the rainbow gradient here, but there are 3 more colors in the css, and which color is shown is randomized. When the same color is selected twice or more in a row, the animation stops and I have a solid gradient behind the text. When another color is selected, the animation kicks back in.
It is supposed to look like this:
[image: What it is supposed to look like]

But being selected twice in a row, it becomes like this:
[image: the problem]